# View not updating in Vue 2 (using Vue.set on object property in component)

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I know I have to use Vue.set(object,property,value) to ensure reactivity in Vue but the following code isn't working.

Component:

```
Vue.component('answer-block', {
  props: ['letters'],
  template: `
    <div>
  <div id='keyboard' v-if="mode==='type'">
  <div :key='idx' :style='letterStyle(letter)' :class='letterClass(letter)' v-for='(letter,idx) in letters' @click='setLetter(letter,"click")'>{{letter.letter}}</div>
  </div>
    </div>
    `
```

Component method "setLetter":

```
Vue.set(selected,'correct',true);
```

Component method "letterClass":

```
return {
  "key": true,
  "correct": letter.correct === true
 };
```

Problem: Class "correct" is not being applied to div when letter property "correct" is set to "true"
Partial solution: View updates when using "this.$forceUpdate();" but not without calling this function

How do I get view to update reactively without calling forceUpdate in above case?

Many thanks.

Comment: A codepen/jsfiddle might help us figure out the problem :)

Comment: Is it should be `Vue.set(letter,'correct',true);`?